# Would this be true for complexity classes?

Tags: complexity-theory

For each integer k > 1, define the complexity class:
 $QP_{k}:= \cup_{c>0} Time(2^{c  * log^{k} n})$

Then for all integers k > 1, $QP_{k} \subset QP_{k+1}$.

Would this be a true assertion?

Anyone know? :(

Comment: I have a feeling it is false but I'm having a hard time with the justification